# How to parse YAML file using python and Flask and display the results on the web?

Tags: python, flask, yaml

I would like to build a simple web application that able to display the results of parsing YAML files using python and Flask. I've been written the code and it works, but the results not the same as expected.
Here's my code:

```
import yaml
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, redirect, url_for
#from pathlib import Path
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def my_form_post():
    #path=Path('/Users/Devie Andriyani/EditFlask/categories.yaml') # set the path to your file here
    #if not path.exists():path.touch()
    if request.method == 'POST':
       #with open(path, 'w') as f:
           #f.write(request.form.get('Text Area',None))
        return redirect(url_for('my_form_post'))

    #with open(r'C:\Users\Devie Andriyani/EditFlask/categories.yaml') as f:
    #my_dict = yaml.safe_load(f)
    a_yaml_file = open("categories.yaml")
parsed_yaml_file = yaml.load(a_yaml_file, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
print(parsed_yaml_file["countries"])
print(parsed_yaml_file["sports"])
return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

And here's my HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <head>
      <title>Hello</title>
   </head>

   <body>
      <form action="" method="POST">
            <p>Text Area</p>
            <p><textarea name="Text Area" rows="20" cols="50" value={{categories}}></textarea>
            </p>
            <input type="submit">
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

And here's my YAML file:

```
sports:
- soccer
- football
- basketball
- cricket
- hockey
- table tennis

countries:
- Pakistan
- USA
- India
- China
- Germany
- France
- Spain
```

And here's the result:
[I want the results of parsing show on the text area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoAsJ.jpg)

Comment: what is expected output? and what you are getting now.

Comment: The expected output is the parsing results are displayed on the text area/web page, not on the (command prompt). I am getting that the parsing results are displayed on the console, not on the text area/web page

Comment: as per your code, you are just opening the file and passing it to front end. that's it right.. do you want to pass the data to somewhere?

Comment: I want to show the data into the front-end, not just on the console. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You opened the file, saved it in a variable, but you didn't pass that to the front-end. You just print it, that why it is printing in the console. You have to pass this to the frontend.

```
parsed_yaml_file = yaml.load(a_yaml_file, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
# print(parsed_yaml_file["countries"]) # this will print in console not in frontend
# print(parsed_yaml_file["sports"])  # this too
return render_template('index.html', yml = parsed_yaml_file)
```

Here I passed the file content `parsed_yaml_file` to the frontend with the name `yml`. So we can access this in the frontend now. But one problem we have. `yaml.load` will return a dictionary. And if you want to display as a dictionary, then no worries. But if you want to display as `YAML` format itself, then you should not convert it into yaml. You directly pass the file `a_yaml_file`.

Suppose if you want yaml output, (hope you passed `yml = a_yaml_file`) then in frontend you have to use `pre` tag.

```
<pre>{{ yml }}</pre>
```

If you want a dictionary, (pass `yml = parsed_yaml_file`) then just use this in frontend

```
{{ yml }}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, @NavaneethaKrishnan for your brilliant answer. But I still confused about which code should I change? I am really sorry, I am just a beginner and a learner.

Comment: In python file update the render_template function. there you have to pass the content to frontend

Comment: Hi @Navaneetha, I have been changed the code based on your answer, but the output doesn't change

Comment: Thank you so so much, @Navaneetha. Your answer really helps me. My problem has been solved.